# How to call useQuery hook conditionally?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, react-query, react-apollo-hooks

Because of the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), one shouldn't call hooks conditionally. So how does one fetch data conditionally using `useQuery`? For example, let's say I want to fetch data inside a functional component, but only if `someState === someValue`? i.e I want to avoid calling `useQuery()` before any conditions because fetching data at these time doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

##### React-Apollo:

In apollo's [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#skip), it shows that there's a skip option you can add:

```
useQuery(query,{skip:someState===someValue})
```

Otherwise, you can also [`useLazyQuery`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery) if you want to have a query that you run when you desire it to be run rather than immediately.

If you are using the suspense based hooks `useSuspenseQuery` and `useBackgroundQuery` you need to use the new [`skipToken`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#skiptoken) import as the options, since the `skip` option is deprecated for these new hooks.

```js
import { skipToken, useSuspenseQuery } from '@apollo/client';
const { data } = useSuspenseQuery(
  query,
  id ? { variables: { id } } : skipToken
);
```

---

Edit: 2 Years after the question was posted, the question tags were edited to add "react-query" which wasn't in the original question.

##### React-Query

As mentioned in the other answer, you can use the `enabled` flag in **[React Query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/dependent-queries)**. Code example from the documentation link.

```
// Get the user
const { data: user } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['user', email],
  queryFn: getUserByEmail,
})

const userId = user?.id

// Then get the user's projects
const {
  status,
  fetchStatus,
  data: projects,
} = useQuery({
  queryKey: ['projects', userId],
  queryFn: getProjectsByUser,
  // The query will not execute until the userId exists
  enabled: !!userId,
})
```

Comment: This has been replaced by `enabled` flag: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/dependent-queries

Comment: I added the answer for React Query in, but it's important to note that the original question was about React-Apollo, which is a *very* different library, and the `skip` property hasn't been deprecated for that.

Comment: Note that with the enabled flag, you are still able to make the request using the returned refetch method from useQuery, regardless of the condition you put inside the enabled option.

Answer (score 24):

You can also use the enabled property of useQuery options for the conditional queries.

```
 // Get the user
 const { data: user } = useQuery(['user', email], getUserByEmail)

 const userId = user?.id

 // Then get the user's projects
 const { isIdle, data: projects } = useQuery(
 ['projects', userId],
 getProjectsByUser,
  {
    // The query will not execute until the userId exists
    enabled: !!userId,
  }
 )
```

Comment: Can you share in the documentation where i can find more on this? i cant find it and would like to read more about it

Comment: @Gabriel The syntax is for react-query, as specified here https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQuery?from=reactQueryV3&original=https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer.

Comment: isIdle not exist in v4, fetchStatus can be used for idle state. When is used enabled flag, and is false, isLoading is always true in v4.

Comment: IMO this has just morphed into a fugly DSL.

Comment: simple form for checking UseQuery with null, I tried with this one useRequest(myId, { enabled: !!myId})